# Can I use Web authorization broker to navigate to a third party payment gateway?

Tags: windows-store-apps, payment-gateway, kiosk

I want to create a windows store shopping cart application (more like a kiosk type) which uses third party payment gateways like Paypal or Authorize.net for payment transaction. I am currently planning to do the payment operation by navigating into the payment gateway site with help of  *web authentication broker*. Since I'm pretty new to the windows store app, is this is the right way to do the transaction process. I mean navigating from store app and came back after payment completion?